# Rolling Index (Dynamic index name) in Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data

I have a use case in which I want to index my document in a separate index based on a certain condition.
For example, I want to store an invoice document to an index with department name suffixed with it.

```java
@Document(indexName="store_{department}", indexStoreType="invoice")
public class InvoiceES{

    // fields
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field
    private String department;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this using Spring Data?

If not, is it planned in a coming release of Spring Data?

Comment: Yo, I know that my question is not related to yours, but... How did you do to update dynamically your index? I mean, you have store_{department}. Could you explain me how can I update dynamically the name of the index please? I'm breaking my brain trying to make it works...

Comment: Seeking/Storing an environment-specific configuration (`indexName` in this case) in code is not a good idea, not sure why Spring folks took this decision.

Answer (score 7):

As far as the spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch-1.5, you can achieve it by spring el expression:

```
@Bean
Department department() {
    return new Department();
}

@Document(indexName="store_#{department.name()}", indexStoreType="invoice")
public class InvoiceES{}
```

You can change the bean's property to change the index you want to save/search:

```
    invoiceRepo.save(new Invoice(...));
    department.setName("newName");
    invoiceRepo.save(new Invoice(...));
```

What should be noticed is not to share this bean in multiple thread, which may mess up your index.

Comment: Is this method still up to date? I heared that the template approach does only work once during repo initialization. Is that true?
And what would you recommend to implement thread safety?

Comment: @FabianTe Yes, you are right that the later version disabled this feature. You may refer to this [issuse](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-387?filter=-2) and this [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/184) for detail. When it comes to thread safety, I use a thread local to store the index suffix, which may suitable for you.

Comment: @Tony If I use "@Scope("prototype")" will this feature be thread safe? what do you think

Answer (score 3):

I had to solve similar problem to store data with dynamic index name, consisting of current date: "Index-name-YYYY.MM.DD".

I made a component which has getter of formatted date string:

```
@Component
public class ElasticIndex {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd");

    public String getIndexDate() {
        return formatter.format(LocalDate.now());
    }
}
```

Thus, your document class will be like that:

```
@Document(indexName = "my_data-#{elasticIndex.getIndexDate()}", type = "DataDoc")
public class DataDoc {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String dataToStore;
    ....
}
```

So each time you save/delete/etc new document to your elasticsearch repository, it gets index name from getIndexDate method of ElasticIndex bean.

Works on Spring Boot 2.2.5, Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.5

Answer (score 1):

```
@Document(indexName = "#{'${elasticsearch.index.name}'}", type = "category", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
```

It created index: `"${elasticsearch.index.name}"`

I tried with spring-data-elasticsearch version 1.1.2.RELEASE and 1.2.0.M1 but according  to jira (https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-93) it is fixed in version 1.1 RC1

Answer (score 0):

Vishal,

Currently spring data elasticsearch does not support this feature. we already have feature request(pull request) which will be added soon with next release.

Have a look on this pull request,
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/56

Answer (score 0):

Spring will create Elasticsearch[Rest]Template bean which implements ElasticsearchOperations.

The ElasticsearchOperations interface offer index(IndexQuery query) function to save a document.

You can use IndexQueryBuilder.withIndexName to overwrite the index name.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [pull request](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-93) link posted earlier, I was able to stitch together a solution. Currently, support is there only for beans of type `String`, and they can be injected into the attribute using [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html), with special `@` notation.

First Define a Bean that returns the dynamic prefix:

```java
@Bean
String department() {
    return "some-department";
}
```

Next, use that in the Elastic Document. Please make a note of the special `@` notation.

```
@Document(indexName = "#{@department}_department")
```

Notes: Actual [requirement](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/668) for Spring.

Answer (score -4):

The only way I found to do this is doing it manually without @Document anotation:

```
        client = new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(nodeId, port));

        IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex(your_index, type, subid)
                .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                                .startObject()
                                .field("field1", field1))
                                .field("fileld2", field2)
                                ).endObject())
                .execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: In such way, you just will create the index in ES itself, but not set up an index for saving/searching documents using ESRepository.