# Dynamic Index with SpringData ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

How can I parameterize a SpringData ElasticSearch index *at runtime*?

For example, the data model:

```
@Document(indexName = "myIndex")
public class Asset {

    @Id
    public String id;

    // ...
}
```

and the repository:

```
public interface AssetRepository extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<Asset, String> {

    Asset getAssetById(String assetId);
}
```

I know I can replace `myIndex` with a parameter, but that parameter will be resolved during instantiation / boot. We have the same Asset structure for multiple clients / tenants, which have their own index. What I need is something like this:

```
public interface AssetRepository extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<Asset, String> {

    Asset getAssetByIdFromIndex(String assetId, String index);
}
```

or this

```
repoInstance.forIndex("myOtherIndex").getAssetById("123");
```

I know this does not work out of the box, but is there any way to programmatically 'hack' it?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894618/creating-indices-name-dynamically-in-elasticsearch-using-spring-data-elasticsear?s=1|2.2393) or [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333327/rolling-index-dynamic-index-name-in-spring-data-elasticsearch?s=2|2.0926) should help.

Comment: I believe neither do (found and studied both before). Those are about not hard coding the index name, but I need to be able to call to many different indexes. I only know the index name via a client parameter (not at compile or boot time)

Comment: Gotcha, let's find another solution then :)

Answer (score 2):

Even though the bean is init at boot time, you can still achieve it by spring expression language:

```
@Bean
Name name() {
    return new Name();
}

@Document(indexName="#{name.name()}")
public class Asset{}
```

You can change the bean's property to change the index you want to save/search:

```
    assetRepo.save(new Asset(...));
    name.setName("newName");
    assetRepo.save(new Asset(...));
```

What should be noticed is not to share this bean in multiple thread, which may mess up your index.

Here is [a working example](https://github.com/zzt93/elasticsearch_demo/blob/dynamicIndex/src/test/java/com/superid/query/user/role/RoleRepoTest.java).

Comment: receiving Page not found on the above link.

Comment: This solution is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticSearchRepository` has a method

```
FacetedPage<T> search(SearchQuery searchQuery);
```

where SearchQuery can take multiple indices to be used for searching.

I hope it answers